# How to assign HeighRequest of a ListView depending on the length of the text of the labels inside it?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a `ListView` which in its `DataTemplate` has a `ViewCell` with 2 `Labels`. What I want to do is that the size of the `ListView` is proportional to the text that these two `Labels` have. If they don't contain text, make the `ListView` very small, if it contains a lot of text, make the size large.

Thats my actual code:

```
    <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" HeightRequest="{Binding heightList}" ItemsSource="{Binding sourceList}" SelectionMode="Single" SeparatorColor="Transparent" SeparatorVisibility="None">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                   <Label FontSize="14" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Text="{Binding text1}" />
                   <Label FontSize="14" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Text="{Binding text2}" />
                </StackLayout>
             </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just not bind isVisible to if text1/text2 is not ""? like

```
bool IsTxt1Vis { get { return text1 != ""; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is that the size of the ListView is proportional to the text that these two Labels have. If they don't contain text, make the ListView very small, if it contains a lot of text, make the size large.

According to your description, you want to adjust height of listview to be minimum size to fit children? If yes, you can use binding ListView HeightRequestto do.

firstly, please set ListView  `VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"`,otherwise the listview's heightrequest in StackLayout will be ignored.

```
<StackLayout>
        <ListView
            BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            HeightRequest="{Binding rowHeigth}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding sourceList}"
            MinimumHeightRequest="50"
            VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label
                                FontSize="14"
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                Text="{Binding text1}" />
                            <Label
                                FontSize="14"
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                Text="{Binding text2}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Button
            x:Name="addbtn"
            Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
            Text=" add data in listview" />
    </StackLayout>


 public partial class Page5 : ContentPage
{
   
    public Page5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
     
        this.BindingContext = new listviewmodel();
    }
}

public class listviewmodel:ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<listmodel> sourceList { get; set; }
    private int _rowHeigth;
    public int rowHeigth
    {
        get { return _rowHeigth; }
        set
        {
            _rowHeigth = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("rowHeigth");
        }
    }
    public ICommand AddCommand { protected set; get; }
    public listviewmodel()
    {
        sourceList = new ObservableCollection<listmodel>()
        {
            new listmodel(){text1="test 1",text2="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},
            new listmodel(){text1="test 1",text2="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},
            new listmodel(){text1="test 1bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",text2="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"},
            new listmodel(){text1="test 1",text2="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},
            new listmodel(){text1="test 1",text2="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"}
        };
        rowHeigth = sourceList.Count * 40;

        AddCommand = new Command<listmodel>(async (key) => {
            sourceList.Add(new listmodel() { text1 = "test 1", text2 = "aaaaaaaaaa" });
            rowHeigth = sourceList.Count * 40;
        });
    }

}
public class listmodel
{
    public string text1 { get; set; }
    public string text2 { get; set; }
}
```

The ViewModelBase is class that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

```
 public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it answer your question or you find it helpful, please let me know by accepting it✅ otherwise you may leave me a feedback/comment.